# Should I use Google site search or a custom database search for my site?

Tags: search, full-text-search, google-search

I'm coding a resource site around a fairly large directory database, and I'd like to make some kind of in-site search available for my visitors. I'm debating between whether to use Google's premade site search (which I can drop right into my template) or coding a custom search that accesses the database directly.

Obviously, the custom search will take alot more work - but if Google can't offer close to the level of results that a custom can, I'll do it. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the google search. It's what they do.

If you don't want to be dependant on them, then look at one of the free search utilities such as htdig. Or a plugin to whatever website engine you're using.